# NDSolve with a limiting condition on dependent variable

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to solve $x'(t)=f(g(x),t), ~x(0)=0$, where $f$ is a function and $g(x)$ is an interpolating function (obtained in Mathematica as a result of some previous calculation) defined only over the interval $[0,x_0]$. The reason for this limitation on $g(x)$ is that finding data points requires numerical integration and beyond $x_0$, `NIntegrate` converges too slowly. How do I use `NDSolve` so that it stops integrating $x'(t)=f(g(x),t)$ as soon as $x$ reaches $x_0$? Is there some simple modification of the following code:
`NDSolveValue[ {x'[t]==f[g[x[t]],t], x[0]=0}, x, {t,0,SomeTimeValue}]` that will do the trick?

Comment: What exactly is $f(x,t)$?

Comment: @zhk $f(x,t)$ is actually velocity of a particle in an unsteady flow. It is obtained by interpolation of fluid velocity at different points in space-time. The actual problem is more complicated and two dimensional, so $f$ depends on y coordinate as well. But I have simplified the problem here to its bare essentials. In summary $f$ involves an interpolating function $g(x)$ obtained from Mathematica, so actually I should be writing $f(g(x),t)$.

Comment: @zhk In the wake of your comment I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) is the obvious tool, and practically, it should be acceptable.  Given the discretization of numerical algorithms, one cannot guarantee that the `NDSolve` will not step past $x_0$. Indeed, it will normally have to, since a discrete step is unlikely to land directly on $x_0$; further, most methods evaluate the ODE at several points in a neighborhood containing each step.  So using `WhenEvent` almost certainly will evaluate `g[x[t]]` outside its domain.  But normally it will only be slightly outside the domain and the extrapolated value(s) should not have a great error.

```
g = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]/4, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> All]

Block[{f},
  f[x_, t_] := x^2 + t^2;
  xIF = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[g[x[t]], t], x[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[x[t] == 5, "StopIntegration"]},
    x, {t, 0, 10}]
  ];
```

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {5.05353} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
>
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {5.05353} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.